# Upserting 'rows' mongodb

Tags: c++, arrays, mongodb, collections, bson

I have a remote processes that generate JSON objects and send them to a server that stores then in a MongoDB. I would like to store these objects in what I would call rows (coming from an SQL background) within a ‘master’ collection for example:

Results (Main Collection)

Results.Day
    Results.Day.1.Data
Results.2
    Results.Day.2.Data
etc

I am using an upsert because as the day proceeds some of the results will be regenerated by the remote processes so will need updating. At present I can upsert Results.Day.1 however when I attempt to upsert Results.Day.2 I get an error saying I have a duplicate key.

I am using the following query for my first upsert:

{ _id: ‘UUID’, Results.Day: { “$eq”: 1 } }

and for the second upsert:

{ _id: ‘UUID’, Results.Day: { “$eq”: 2 } }

Is it even possible to do this, and if so how can I do it? I would appreciate your thoughts on this. It is obvious I am no expert on NoSQL but from my limited understanding it would appear that I need to insert the 'rows' as arrays, but how I do this I do not know.

I have access to the source code to both the client and server so can change what is needed in order to accomplish this, so I would really appreciate help on this.

I am using for the Server

MongoDB v3.0.4 on Linux and the legacy-0.0-26compat c++ driver.
Windows 7 x64 and the same driver for the Client.

EDIT:

Ok, based on the comments below and on further reading I see that I simply can't change the _id key. However, if I hand craft a document to mimic what I am trying to achieve in code I can load it in to the database without error :

```
{
"_id": "aebc483c-5832-45ac-8a43-16b2c591b520",
"Results":
{
"Day":
    {
        "19":
        {
            "Data":
            {
                Blah
            }
        },
    "201":
        {
            "Data":
            {
                More Blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But when I upsert using :

```
{
"_id": "aebc483c-5832-45ac-8a43-16b2c591b520",
"Results":
{
"Day":
    {
        "20":
        {
            "Data":
            {
                Blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

It replaces what I already have in the database instead of inserting Day 20 into the collection, needless to say this is not what I want. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: The `_id` field is a "primary key" and therefore always required to be unique. If you require `_id` and `Results.Day` in combination for unique entries then either A: "Compound those values within the `_id` field, probably as an object. B: Have two "external" fields as the unique identifer outside of the `_id` field and let MongoDB automatically fill that with the default `ObjectId`. Right now it looks like you are sending the "same" UUID value as already in `_id` in order to get that error.

Comment: It is the same UUID as this is the document I want to add the data to. I know what a compound index is but how to do it is another matter; so I shall google.

Comment: You could "read" what is said there `_id` **must be unqiue**. It's not just about a compound index, it's about what you put in `_id`. The "copound" I mentioned is "compund key", as in `{ "_id": { "uuid": "actualvalue", "day": "dayvalue" } }`

Comment: By the way:  `Results.Day: { “$eq”: 2 }` can be written as just `Results.Day: 2`

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. But I interpreted what you said as: If I create a unique compound index (key) based on UUID and Results.Day then I should be able to upsert as I described above. Or have I mis-understood?

Comment: OK, I'm even more confused now. Having modified the code I now get this: The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: "aebc483c-5832-45ac-8a43-16b2c591b520"} to {_id: " uuid: "aebc483c-5832-45ac-8a43-16b2c591b520", Results.Day: "18" }" While inserting to an empty collection. How can I replace the index with my own one?

Comment: Is anyone willing to tell me how I need to format my JSON and what I need to do to have it upserted into my database? I'm not wanting code only guidance from those that know much more than me. I'd really appreciate it.